Engines and blocked positions
Take your typical totally blocked position, like this one:

Is there an engine today which, on an ordinary laptop, is capable of assessing it as 0.00 in a few seconds?
Position for testing:
FEN (White to move):
k1r2b2/1r6/3p1p2/p1pPpPp1/PpP1P1Pp/1P5P/1R6/2K3B1 w - - 0 1
FEN (Black to move):
k1r2b2/1r6/3p1p2/p1pPpPp1/PpP1P1Pp/1P5P/1R6/2K3B1 b - - 0 1

There is a good chance Crystal can - https://www.chessprogramming.org/Crystal. However I have not tried it and so am not writing it as an answer.

There is a performant engine to determine whether positions are dead from one side or both sides. See deadpos.
This isn't the same as blocked positions, such as the example given, where the players could break through if they co-operated. However there are some surprisingly tricky positions, often related to tempo, which deadpos correctly classifies.

Stockfish on chesscom can assess it, as well as stockfish on any other GUI. Same with any other modern chess engine such as Komodo, Komodo dragon, lc0... I tested this out on my dads old thinkpad. It assessed it as 0.0. At least in my personal experience it has.

My Stockfish on chess.com is stuck at -2.96 after many minutes, at maximum depth. And I have a Diamond account, so it must be the strongest engine available there.
